# Unlock a TABSTable by code

Tags: delphi, absolute-db

I have a `TABSTable` (Absolute database Table).

Sometimes, I get an error message that tells me that the table is locked.

How to unlock the table by code?

Comment: Have you read http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/lockingandmulti_useraccess.htm ?

Answer (score 2):

From documentation: http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/lockingandmulti_useraccess.htm

> Absolute Database is designed to do simplify development of multi-user
>   database application as much as possilbe.  Locking is performed only
>   when database is open in multi-user mode. To gain multi-user access to
>   a database, set TABSDatabase.MultiUser to True before opening a
>   database file.
>
> Locking
>
> Absolute Database uses locking to ensure transactional integrity and
>   database consistency. Locking prevents users from reading data being
>   changed by other users, and prevents multiple users from changing the
>   same data at the same time. If locking is not used, data within the
>   database may become logically incorrect, and queries executed against
>   that data may produce unexpected results.

Comment: I have already read the help file but I have not found how to unlock a locked table.
When the table is locked, the default time-outs: 1.5 seconds for record level locking, 90 seconds for table locking.
For the table locking, what value should I change please?
Const SelectTablesLockRetries = 900;
or
Const EditRecordTableLockRetries = 900;
or
Const SelectTablesLockRetries = 900;
or
...

Comment: You said "Sometimes, I get an error message that tells me that the table is locked." that means that another user/application is locking that table. That's the purpose of locking.